# How much will global warming increase the density of debris in LEO? What are predictions currently saying?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, planetary-science, debris, climate

After about `08:00` in Scott Manley's hot off the press new release *SpaceX Loses 40 Satellites To Solar Storm* linked below he drifts away from the solar activity-induced heating and talks about the long term effects of global warming on the Earth's mesosphere and thermosphere.

Apparently the same changes that will trap more heat at lower altitudes will result a cooling at higher altitudes, and therefore (according to him and whatever he's reading) decay rates of objects in LEO will decrease.

This could potentially be a big deal at some altitudes since even a small decrease in average temperature will result in a dramatic decrease in density a dozen or two scale heights above the Karman line.

**Question:** How much will global warming increase the density of debris in LEO? What are predictions currently saying?

It's an easy question to ask and a complicated one to try to answer. Models of space debris dynamics will take into account fluctuations of the Sun to some extent, but now they would have to also include a long-term trend somehow, based on climate models.

cued at `07:59`: